# Issues when using pandoc to convert "*.tex" to "*.html"

Tags: html, pandoc, tex

I am in the process of converting a tex document to html using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) and the [xnos filters](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-xnos), and I am facing several issues with figures/tables caption and numbering.

So I tried to convert my tex file using:

```sh
pandoc --filter pandoc-xnos --mathjax manual.tex --bibliography full-biblio.bib --wrap=none --default-image-extension=png -o manual.html
```

[EDIT]
**The results are strictly the same without the xnos filters:**

```sh
pandoc --mathjax manual.tex --bibliography full-biblio.bib --wrap=none --default-image-extension=png -o manual.html
```

**Therefore this is a pandoc related problem only**
[/EDIT]

Then I face 2 issues:

1. Figure ref are found and numbered in the document, **only and only if**, the reference appears after that the figure was inserted, note in the HTML data the **[my_img]** in the first example and the **[1.0]** in the second one:

```tex
Figure \ref{my_img} presents some information.

\begin{figure}[!h]
\hypertarget{my_img}{
\begin{center}
\includegraphics*[width=23cm, keepaspectratio=true]{my-image}
\caption{My legend}\label{overview}
\end{center}}
\end{figure}
```

Is converted in:

```html
<p>[Fig. <a href="#my_img" data-reference-type="ref" data-reference="my_img">my_img</a>-a] presents some information.</p>

<div id="my_img">
<div align="center">
<figure>
<img src="my-image.png" id="overview" style="width:23cm" alt="My legend" />
<figcaption aria-hidden="true">My legend</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
</div>
```

Whereas:

```tex
\begin{figure}[!h]
\hypertarget{my_img}{
\begin{center}
\includegraphics*[width=23cm, keepaspectratio=true]{my-image}
\caption{My legend}\label{overview}
\end{center}}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{my_img} presents some information.
```

Is converted in:

```html
<div id="my_img">
<div align="center">
<figure>
<img src="my-image.png" id="overview" style="width:23cm" alt="My legend" />
<figcaption aria-hidden="true">My legend</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
</div>

<p>[Fig. <a href="#my_img" data-reference-type="ref" data-reference="my_img">1.0</a>-a] presents some information.</p>
```

2. The caption never show numbers, actually the beginning part of the caption, that should be "Figure #num:" (or something close) is always missing (just see above).

Any help to understand what I am doing wrong or missing would be really appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: Why are you wrapping your image in a hypertarget? The label automatically creates a target.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `center` environment inside a figure, this result in incorrect vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead

Comment: I need to use the `center` environnent, with `centering` it is not possible to get the `<div align="center">` to center the figure on the web page, for the `hypertarget` it appears on all the examples I found far ... and it does not change the end result of the wrong and missing captions

Comment: I think most people use the xnos filters to go from markdown to LaTeX/PDF or from markdown to HTML... so maybe your use-case isn't as well supported? or maybe I'm wrong..